# Large Bluetooth Mouse

Tags: wireless-networking, mouse, bluetooth

I'm currently using a [Logitech MX Revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logitech_MX_Revolution). Unfortunately, it operates on the 2.4 GHz band which results in some horrible interferance with my wireless network.

I'm looking for recommendations wireless mice that work well in close proximity to a wireless network. As I also spend many hours with a mouse in hand, I'd much prefer a larger mouse, and the small to regular sized ones really start to cramp up my hand. Do any large Bluetooth mice exist?

Comment: bluetooth uses the same 2.4 ghz frequency

Comment: Ah, good to know! Hmm... then I'm really open to suggestions.

Comment: The Journeyman geek - Yes, very very true, but the 802.11b/g/n and recent Bluetooth specifications have measures to help mitigate the effect of interference.  Switching to a Bluetooth mouse won't eliminate the interference, but it would cooperate a little better.

That is a very nice mouse you have though.  Have you tried changing the channel on your wireless network?  I did that when I had problems after getting my VX Nano mouse.

Since most newer wireless mice run in the 2.4Ghz range, if you keep having problems you could go with an older mouse or upgrade your Wi-Fi to dual-band N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across the [Wireless Laser Mouse 8000](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/mouseandkeyboard/productdetails.aspx?pid=084).